# Button Extends in size when clicked

Tags: php, css, wordpress

In my Wordpress site, when the "READ MORE" button is clicked, the button extends in size and makes a large "black" block before directing to the relevant link?

I have tried changing the 'hover' color of the button to 'transparent' but it just takes the words: "READ MORE" to the top of the transparent block?

[Website Link](http://ogatinplastics.com/products/)

```
a.button.add_to_cart_button, 
a.button.product_type_simple { 
    bottom: 22px; 
    position: absolute; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the .woocommerce-page a.button:active has a top:0; , you should change that as follows:

```
a.button:active {
    top: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that works great, thanks